# Search path for typescript .d.ts files

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to get the typescript compiler to search for declaration files in a given directory? Something like the INCLUDE_PATH for C++.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not currently.

You have to reference the file explicitly using:

```
///<reference path="path/to/file.d.ts" />
```

You can use the references.ts trick to ease the referencing in your program (just put all your references in a single file so all your other files just point to that one).

*UPDATE*

As of TypeScript 0.9.1, the Visual Studio template just gives you access to all of the TypeScript files and TypeScript definition files in your project. I have tested this and it works...

You can [see the example and notes about this feature](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201308/Blog/Say-Goodbye-To-TypeScript-Reference-Comments/) in my blog post.

*Update for Visual Studio 2013 Update 3*

I have updated the above article to point out that you must have the build action set to `TypeScriptCompile` for a file to be included in this automatic discovery.

Comment: Or you can a grunt plugin I wrote to add these for you : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation :)

Comment: Acutally I just spent today making this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km0DpfX5ZxM If you already know grunt : http://youtu.be/Km0DpfX5ZxM?t=11m16s And specifically the reference file creation demo : http://youtu.be/Km0DpfX5ZxM?t=14m6s

Comment: @SteveFenton: Do you mean that VS scans the whole project and automatically includes any ts files? I've got the jQuery.d.ts typings file, and I find that my ts file simply will not work unless I reference the file either by absolute path relative to the whole hard drive (which is inconvenient) or the path relative to my ts file (also inconvenient, because I have to be very careful about nesting).

Comment: @JoshuaFrank it should scan any file marked with the `TypeScriptCompile` build action.

Comment: @SteveFenton: I don't think this works. I've got a typings file with a `TypeScriptCompile` build action, but VS does not see it unless the file is explicitly referenced.

Comment: Are you able to create a small working example as this may be a bug, or a combination of settings (for example if you are using AMD or CommonJS you need an import or reference).