# About "*.d.ts" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am curious about `.d.ts` declaration files. I was told by someone that `.d.ts` files are similar to `.h` header files in the C & C++ programming languages, however, the `.d.ts` files don't seem to work quite the same. Currently, I am failing to understand how to properly use the .d.ts files.

It would appear that I can't add my `.js` or `.ts` files to the `.d.ts` files, so the only way my project will work is if it contains all three file types. My questions are:

1. What is the relationship between the three files?
2. How can I use the `*.d.ts` file, does it mean I can delete the `*.ts` file permanently?
3. If so, how can the `*.d.ts` file know which JS file is mapping to itself?

Comment: For future people: check out the TypeScript doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

Comment: I created a new post with a working answer for Ionic 7 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77729365/include-a-javascript-file-in-a-typescript-ionic-project)

Answer (score 888, accepted):

The "d.ts" file is used to provide typescript type information about an API that's written in JavaScript. The idea is that you're using something like jQuery or underscore, an existing javascript library. You want to consume those from your typescript code.

Rather than rewriting jquery or underscore or whatever in typescript, you can instead write the d.ts file, which contains only the type annotations. Then from your typescript code you get the typescript benefits of static type checking while still using a pure JS library.

This works thanks to TypeScript's constraint of not letting you add the ".ts" extension at the end of the `import` statement. Because of that, when you reference some file, let's say, `my-module.js`, if there is a `my-module.d.ts` next to it, then TypeScript will include its content:

```yaml
src/
  my-module.js
  my-module.d.ts
  index.ts
```

<sub>*my-module.js*</sub>

```js
const thing = 42;

module.exports = { thing };
```

<sub>*my-module.d.ts*</sub>

```
export declare const thing: number;
```

<sub>*index.ts*</sub>

```
import { thing } from "./my-module"; // <- no extension

// runtime implementation of `thing` is taken from ".js"
console.log(thing); // 42

// type declaration of `thing` is taken from ".d.ts"
type TypeOfThing = typeof thing; // number
```

Comment: Many thanks! But how to map a *.d.ts file to a js file? How does the js file know which d.ts file is mapping to itself? Can you give me an example?

Comment: The .js file knows nothing about the .d.ts file - those files are for other .ts files, not the js files. More later.

Comment: But the d.ts file is generated from the js file, and if the js file knows nothing about d.ts. How to call the functions from d.ts in other ts files without the js file? I'm puzzled......

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091724/search-path-for-typescript-d-ts-files. You need to add a ///<reference line to the top of the consuming ts file. You'll need to have both the d.ts and the .js file available.

Comment: the d.ts file is generally handwritten from js file documentation. A large number of these are available for popular javascript libraries : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Where do you put custom d.ts files if you're making custom ones for your project?

Comment: Here's [one example in React.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2beec2f308e27dbe902a8d68e1fc9f3d70ee9372/src/isomorphic/modern/class/__tests__/ReactTypeScriptClass-test.ts) that links to `d.ts` file explicitly. Of course, and its [generator](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b1768b5a48d1f82e4ef4150e0036c5f846d3758a/scripts/jest/ts-preprocessor.js#L28)

Comment: For those interested, a page describing where `.d.ts` files are [searched for](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: I've added a usage example for a `.d.ts` file. Hope that answers some of your questions!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if you are just creating a project with Typescript there is absolutely no need for any .d.ts file, right?

Comment: Correct. The .d.ts file is used for javascript files that are consumed by Typescript projects.

Comment: @ChrisTavares not entirely correct. If the project is importing a 3rd party library that exposes a global namespace (such as window.[property]), then typescript will complain about it until a global type definition is available: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html

Answer (score 154):

`d` stands for [Declaration Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#Declaration_files):

> When a TypeScript script gets compiled there is an option to generate
>   a declaration file (with the extension .d.ts) that functions as an
>   interface to the components in the compiled JavaScript. In the process
>   the compiler strips away all function and method bodies and preserves
>   only the signatures of the types that are exported. The resulting
>   declaration file can then be used to describe the exported virtual
>   TypeScript types of a JavaScript library or module when a third-party
>   developer consumes it from TypeScript.
>
> The concept of declaration files is analogous to the concept of header
>   file found in C/C++.

```
declare module arithmetics {
    add(left: number, right: number): number;
    subtract(left: number, right: number): number;
    multiply(left: number, right: number): number;
    divide(left: number, right: number): number;
}
```

> Type declaration files can be written by hand for existing JavaScript
>   libraries, as has been done for jQuery and Node.js.
>
> Large collections of declaration files for popular JavaScript
>   libraries are hosted on GitHub in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped) and the [Typings
>   Registry](https://github.com/typings/registry). A command-line utility called [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) is provided to help
>   search and install declaration files from the repositories.

Comment: Note:  the `typings` command line tool isn't really needed since TypeScript 2.0.   The more up-to-date approach is to use typing wrappers via the npm repository under the `@types` namespace.   For further detail see https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @takeshin
I've got a question. Do I need to generate .d.ts files of .tsx files which are used only inside of my project? Does those are adding something else besides of giving possibility 3rd party libraries additional info?

Comment: @Jazi Ideally no, your .tsx files should be enough. Even if you are making a libary which is in TS, you index.ts will contain the types and give access to typechecking as its present in your node_modules after installation.

Answer (score 129):

I learned the following from having to painstakingly map a JavaScript project using `.d.ts` files.

Using a `.d.ts` file to map JavaScript requires that you name your `.d.ts` files the same as you name your `.js` files. Each `.js` file needs to be kept inline (kept in the same directory) with the `.d.ts` file that has the same name. Point the JS/TS code that needs the types from the `.d.ts` files to the `.d.ts` files.

eg: `test.js` and `test.d.ts` are in the `testdir/` folder, then you import it like this in a react component:

```js
import * as Test from "./testdir/test";
```

The `.d.ts` file was exported as a namespace like this:

```js
export as namespace Test;
    
export interface TestInterface1{}
export class TestClass1{}
```

Comment: Nobody gave an answer as to how to connect d.ts to js, so i thought this is the right place.

Comment: Note that if you're creating a declaration file for some JS that you didn't create (a package from npm for example) that the ``.d.ts`` file must also be named the same as the package to be imported.

Comment: What if the module is impored like this (don't ask me why ): `import x from "x/x.js"` i.e. has a file extension at the end? Tried naming the d.ts file `x.js.d.ts` but that doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: file *.d.ts must be "the same name" and the "same folder" with *.js. I think the above answer is right

Answer (score 46):

**Worked example** for a *specific case*:

Let's say you have *my-module* that you're sharing via *npm*.

You install it with `npm install my-module`

You use it thus:

```
import * as lol from 'my-module';

const a = lol('abc', 'def');
```

The module's logic is all in `index.js`:

```
module.exports = function(firstString, secondString) {

  // your code

  return result
}
```

To add typings, create a file `index.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export default function anyName(arg1: string, arg2: string): MyResponse;
}

interface MyResponse {
  something: number;
  anything: number;
}
```

Comment: This example does not explain why you need a `.d.ts` file: you could have `index.ts` with both the code and the types at the same place.

Answer (score 42):

Like @takeshin said .d stands for declaration file for typescript (.ts).

**Few points to be clarified before proceeding to answer this post -**

1. Typescript is syntactic superset of javascript.
2. Typescript doesn't run on its own, it needs to be transpiled into javascript ([typescript to javascript conversion](https://storefront-staging.paytm.com/dev1/v2/h/mumbiker-nikhil?merchant_id=43486&aggregator-bid=1707))
3. "Type definition" and "Type checking" are major add-on functionalities that typescript provides over javascript. ([check difference between type script and javascript](https://stackify.com/typescript-vs-javascript-migrate/))

If you are thinking if typescript is just syntactic superset, what benefits does it offer - https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/why-typescript.html#the-typescript-type-system

**To Answer this post -**

As we discussed, typescript is superset of javascript and needs to be transpiled into javascript. So if a library or third party code is written in typescript, it eventually gets converted to javascript which can be used by javascript project but vice versa does not hold true.

For ex -

If you install javascript library -

```
npm install --save mylib
```

and try importing it in typescript code -

```
import * from "mylib";
```

you will get error.

> "Cannot find module 'mylib'."

As mentioned by @Chris,  many libraries like underscore, Jquery are already written in javascript. Rather than re-writing those libraries for typescript projects, an alternate solution was needed.

In order to do this, you can provide type declaration file in javascript library named as *.d.ts, like in above case mylib.d.ts. Declaration file only provides type declarations of functions and variables defined in respective javascript file.

Now when you try -

```
import * from "mylib";
```

mylib.d.ts gets imported which acts as an interface between javascript library code and typescript project.

Comment: Where exactly do you put mylib.d.ts? Can it be anywhere in your code base? Only at the top level? Does some config file need to point to it?

Answer (score 17):

This answer assumes you have some JavaScript that you don't want to convert to TypeScript, but you want to benefit from type checking with minimal changes to your `.js`.
A `.d.ts` file is very much like a C or C++ header file. Its purpose is to define an interface. Here is an example:

mashString.d.ts

```
/** Makes a string harder to read. */
declare function mashString(
    /** The string to obscure */
    str: string
):string;
export = mashString;
```

mashString.js

```
// @ts-check
/** @type {import("./mashString")} */
module.exports = (str) => [...str].reverse().join("");
```

main.js

```
// @ts-check
const mashString = require("./mashString");
console.log(mashString("12345"));
```

The relationship here is: `mashString.d.ts` defines an interface, `mashString.js` implements the interface and `main.js` uses the interface.

To get the type checking to work you add `// @ts-check`  to your `.js` files.
But this only checks that `main.js` uses the interface correctly. To also ensure that `mashString.js` implements it correctly we add `/** @type {import("./mashString")} */` before the export.

You can create your initial `.d.ts` files using `tsc -allowJs main.js -d` then edit them as required manually to improve the type checking and documentation.

In most cases the implementation and interface have the same name, here `mashString`. But you can have alternative implementations. For example we could rename `mashString.js` to `reverse.js` and have an alternative `encryptString.js`.

Answer (score 8):

From the official documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#dts-files):

> `.d.ts` files are declaration files that contain only type information. These files don’t produce .js outputs; they are only used for typechecking.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I could add my 2 cents here

```js
// somefile.d.ts
export type SomeItem = {
  weight: number
}

export type ItemStorage = {
  name: string
  items: SomeItem[]
}
```

```js
// somefile.js
// @ts-check
/** @typedef { import('./somefile.d.ts').SomeItem } SomeItem */
/** @typedef { import('./somefile.d.ts').ItemStorage } ItemStorage */

/**
 * @param { StorageItem } item
 */
function doSomething(item) {
  item. // intellisense
  // your code here
}
```

The neat thing about this is that one can gradually incorporate types in an existing javascript project.

Answer (score 1):

Since the source code is the final source of truth. Here seems to be the implementation for this:

```js
/*
 * Every module resolution kind can has its specific understanding how to load module from a specific path on disk
 * I.e. for path '/a/b/c':
 * - Node loader will first to try to check if '/a/b/c' points to a file with some supported extension and if this fails
 * it will try to load module from directory: directory '/a/b/c' should exist and it should have either 'package.json' with
 * 'typings' entry or file 'index' with some supported extension
 * - Classic loader will only try to interpret '/a/b/c' as file.
 */
type ResolutionKindSpecificLoader = (extensions: Extensions, candidate: string, onlyRecordFailures: boolean, state: ModuleResolutionState) => Resolved | undefined;
```

and

```js
/**
 * Kinds of file that we are currently looking for.
 */
const enum Extensions {
    TypeScript  = 1 << 0, // '.ts', '.tsx', '.mts', '.cts'
    JavaScript  = 1 << 1, // '.js', '.jsx', '.mjs', '.cjs'
    Declaration = 1 << 2, // '.d.ts', etc.
    Json        = 1 << 3, // '.json'

    ImplementationFiles = TypeScript | JavaScript,
}
```

The full file is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/moduleNameResolver.ts.

Answer (score -4):

For example, you got the problem to use 'alertifyjs' module from npm.

1. Create 'anyNameYoulike.d.ts' (ex. you made this file in src folder)
2. In the file
   **declare module 'alertifyjs';**
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b30Lr.png)
3. in tsconfig.json
   Under "compilerOptions"
   "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/anyNameYoulike.d.ts"]

Comment: Please repost this as a comment.

Comment: @Yserbius How could the length of this answer be a comment?