# What kind of javascript syntax is this: "var XX = (function (){...})();" and how can I use it with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found this in the PDFJS viewer sample:

```
var XX = (function XXClosure() {
  function XX(options) {
    ...
  },
  XX.prototype = {
    myMethod1: function(){...},
    myMethod2: function(){...},
    ...
  }
  return XX;
})();
```

I create a construct like this, without any idea what it is, and used it in a javascript project in this way:

```
var myXX = new XX(myOptions);
myXX.Method1();
```

This works very well.

Now i try to use this construct in a TypeScript project:

```
declare XX:any
import myJavascript.js;
var myXX = new XX(myOptions);
```

and i get at runtime the error: "XX is not a constructor"

Don't ask me why i make it in this way, may be there are others, I copied this from PDFJS viewer.js, it worked and i never asked why.

But now, in the typescript project, it should work too.Has someone a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: Correct but it answers only the first part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're basically creating an ES6 class by using a self-invoking function:, i.e, (function(){})(). This gets assigned to the variable XX.

A similar construct in Typescript would be

```
class XX {
  constructor(options){
    //do stuff with options
  }
  myMethod1(){}
  myMethod2(){}
  ...//additional methods
}
```

You would instantiate this as you would a JS object with

```
var xx = new XX(options);
```

And if you export the class, it should import without any problems.

```
export class XX{...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i know what it is. The class construct is a good idea but i must clarify if i can use ES6 features.

Comment: Typescript allows for classes. Your class will then be transpiled into something that looks alot like your original code. Classes: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html, Modules: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: The code is common code for different projects. It should work for ts- and also for js-projects.

Answer (score 1):

This is called like [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

```
var XX = (function XXClosure() {
      function XX(options) {
        ...
      },
      XX.prototype = {
        myMethod1: function(){...},
        myMethod2: function(){...},
        ...
      }
      return XX;
    })();
```

If you want something to inject from the `JavaScript` into `TypeScript` you must use
`declare` statement in the files with `.d.ts` extensions.

For this see here [.d.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript)

And also you need to use `declare var XX:any` -> thanks to [toskv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5152732/toskv)

Comment: declare works everywhere. he just needs to say it's a variable so declare **var** XX: any;

Comment: @toskv ok. I know that when you want to first run js code you need to put it in the `.d.ts` file

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now i know what it is. I will try the entry in the .d.ts file next time.

Answer (score 1):

First is [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

For TypeScript, you can use `class` ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i know what it is. The class construct is a good idea but i must clarify if i can use ES6 features.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. The first part of my question is complete answered. The second part, i solved by a fluke. I removed the 'use strict' line and I got an meaningful error message: 'using of an undefined variable'.

I use in the 'constructor' a global object variable which is from an other js module that was not loaded at this time. Placing the "script src='...'" in the head block of the main html page and not in the html template, solved my problem.