# Is there any good reason to set the compiler option "declaration" to true in a typescript project

Tags: typescript, npm, typing

I have a typescript project and it's possible that I want to publish it as an NPM package in the future.

Now at the moment I have set `"declaration": true` in  my `tsconfig.json`.
However this causes me some problems (which don't really matter for this question).

If I set it to `false` everything works asI want it to.

The `declaration` flag when set to true, generates `d.ts` files. However my understanding according to the post 
[About "*.d.ts" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript) is, that this is only relevant if you're not already programming in typescript (i.e. your project is javascript), so that you can later easily use this javascript library in a typescript project, because you now have the types.

So why should anyone ever set this setting to `true` when the project is "pure" typescript? Can I safely set it to `false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any good reason to set the compiler option “declaration” to true in a typescript project?

Yes.

Especially if you are going to publish as an NPM package!

## Justification

When you create your NPM package, you should include the `.js` and the `.d.ts` files - and not the `.ts` files. This makes your package really portable, and ensures it can be used by both TypeScript projects *and* plain old JavaScript projects.

This is the recommended packaging mechanism for TypeScript on NPM and more information on publishing can be found in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I came to the same conclusion by my self - thanks for the confirmation ;)