# Getting error "Property 'setName' does not exist on type" when importing a function and setName added onto a prototype, why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, prototype

I have an old code that creates a function. Something like:

```
function oldFunction() {
  this.name = '';
}

oldFunction.prototype.setName = function(name){this.name = name};

module.exports = oldFunction;
```

My "new" code uses this function like this:

```
import { oldFunction } from 'old-function';
export class NewClass extends oldFunction {
  constructor(name) {
    super();
    this.setName(name);
  }
}
```

Using the `NewClass` like this: `const n = new NewClass();` generates an error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'setName' does not exist on type 'NewClass'.
```

The tests pass and it compiles, but this error persists.
This can be fixed by using an `index signature` inside the class - but that's more a hack than a solution.

Why is this happening? Is this a TS bug?

Comment: Is this the same problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871299/how-to-extend-function-with-es6-classes - extends Function (not Class)...

Comment: You will probably want to [use a declaration file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21247278/1048572) to make `oldFunction` and its prototype methods known to the type system.

Comment: @MatthewPage No, that seems quite unrelated

Comment: @MatthewPage - this is not related.
@Bergi - this doesn't seem to work. The tutorials on how to create these files are quite mixed up and unclear, so it might be that I got this wrong.
Do you have a suggested tutorial on how to do that?
I've just added a `@types` folder to my project. Inside I've create a folder: `old-function`.  Inside I've created a file `index.ts`. Inside I've declared `old-function` which exported a class `oldFunction` with the needed methods. Should it work?