# Should I use TypeScript definition files in my own project?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So, as I know there are several ways to use interfaces in TypeScript:

- Declare interfaces in d.ts files and than use them in .ts files
  without import

  Declare interaces in .ts files and import them when we need them

What is best practice to do? Use .d.ts or stick to the `import` in my own TS project?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About "\*.d.ts" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'll want to use `*.d.ts` files when they are part of an external dependency. Most NPM packages come pre-compiled in JavaScript and ship `*.d.ts` files to allow your IDE and the TypeScript compiler to work properly.

When you work in your own project and the files you are referencing are part of that project, you'll want to directly use the `*.ts` files.

Comment: But why? Simply convention?