# React - meaning of a jest-related line in package.json after eject of create-react-app, !src/**/*.d.ts

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

After "yarn eject" from a create-react-app fresh made app, I see this line:

```
// jest section:
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  "!src/**/*.d.ts"
],
```

What does exclamation mark means here, does it mean "not"? what purpose? to not to run typescript as test?

```
"!src/**/*.d.ts"
```

Comment: to filter out *.d.ts files, it's a config file => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript

Comment: Check [rewire](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to avoid eject, may be you found it appropriate