# Set global declaration in vscode JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm working on a JavaScript transpiler that apart from other things will also replace certain functions and variables upon build.

For example the following file (`./src/my-module.js`):

```js
defineModule("MyModule", function(exports) {
  return exports;
});
```

Will be copied and converted to (`./build/my-module.js`):

```js
(function(global, factory) {
  "use strict";
  if (typeof exports !== "undefined" && typeof module !== "undefined") module.exports.MyModule = factory(exports.MyModule || {});
  else factory(global.MyModule = {});
})(this, function(exports) {
  return exports;
});
```

Some of these functions could also return a result. In that case I would like to be able to declare the types of the parameters and the result of the function without using `require`. Is it possible to have a global `.d.ts` definition in VSCode?

So far, all I've done is add the functions to the global variable of `eslint` so as to not have errors.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly. Is this a Typescript project? If yes, what about adding the types to the `paths` config in `tsconfig.json`? Let me know if this is what you are looking for, so I will prepare an answer with details later.

Comment: So you are trying to declare the type of `defineModule` without defining the function (because it will only be inlined by the transpiler, there is no actual callable function anywhere)?

Comment: @saulotoledo, I'm working on a transpiler, which means that Im working on a project (completely besides the point if it is JavaScript or TypeScript) that will alter the contents of JavaScript files. It would be ideal to have the declarations in a global `.d.ts` file somwhere that I can reference from all my projects without the need of a `require` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Acknowledgment

This answer was mostly inspired by [mootrichard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866852/set-global-declaration-in-vscode-javascript/57172766#57172766), but since it had to be modified, to work with my project, I am also adding this answer.

### Solution

If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> on a global JavaScript function (i.e. `eval`) a typing declarations file will appear (`lib.es5.d.ts`), containing JavaScript documentation. You can just add any extra namespaces or function to that file. But you need to use `declare` and not `export`.

Example:

```
//... Other Global JavaScript Declarations

// JavaScript Number Interface
interface Number {
  //...
}

// JavaScript Date Interface
interface Date {
  //...
}

declare function ezDefine(moduleName: string, generator: *): void;
```

Comment: Am I the only one feeling uncomfortable editing files which belong to the `typescript` package that essentially is a vscode dependency?

Comment: I found this helpful. I used node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts and patch-package @types/node

Answer (score 7):

You can specify your own TypeScript folder path in your `settings.json` where you can specify your own `lib.*.d.ts` files using the `typescript.tsdk` option.

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Comment: While I followed your instructions and put my `.d.ts` with the other `.d.ts` files of typescript, VSCode still says the type of `defineModule` is `any`. Also, VSCode was trying to get the `node_modules/typescript/lib` using a path relative to the current workspace instead of the `Roaming/npm/node_modules`. I have temporarily fixed the problem using an absolute path, though I would greatly appreciate it, if you could also point me in the right direction towards fixing this issue.

Comment: Are there any further actions I have to do?

Comment: I think if you had typescript installed globally you'd be able to circumvent this by having it point to the globally defined TypeScript installation. Obviously that'd create problems if your projects are pointing to different versions of TypeScript though.

Comment: Still a bit unclear, if I should create a new file (do I have to declare it?) under the `lib` directory or if I should use one of the existing files (which one?). Should I use `export` or `declare`? Could you please show an example exporting the `defineModule`  function?

Comment: Oh, I figured you already knew how to create your own *.d.ts files and would just add it in there. There are a few examples that show how you can declare and export there elsewhere though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript

Comment: I do know, but just placing a .d.ts file in the `lib ` folder didnt work, so im asking if  I need to include the folder in like typescripts package.json or something

Comment: My bad, it looking a little further into this, the naming convention for creating your own library definition is `lib.*.d.ts` (updated in answer). If you wanted to do something a little bit hacky, you could certainly just add them to `typescript.d.ts` in that folder.

Comment: Figured I would just put the stuff to `typescript.d.ts`. But to access it, I have to do `require("C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib\\typescript")`. That's not very convenient.

Comment: Thanks @mootrichard a lot for your answer, however putting a new file named `lib.*.d.ts` no longer works for the latest TypeScript (4.8 at this moment), it only loads a pre-defined list of files (see `libEntries` in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9d443b76aac0832d7f3c890441264d39307fe31a/lib/tsserver.js)