# When importing, the prototype is not visible

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I have `httpClient` with methods in prototype like `get, post, put` etc. And it's working and visible in this file:

[image: visible prototype]

And i export it:

[image: exported client]

But if i try to import this in another file `import httpClient from './httpClient'`, i dont see prototype methods:

[image]

How to import it with visible methods for this module?

Comment: it's a typescript question and it have something todo that there is no `.d.ts` file for the module (the Declaration File) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript

Comment: Prototype should be there. It doesn't matter that your code editor is not showing it. Could you console log httpClient and check in the console its prototype?

Comment: @LazarNikolic Yes, it's doesn't matter that my editor is not showing, it works, just that uncomfortable

Comment: what if you document it and declare the prototype as a member of the httpClient

Comment: @Marty so, there is a prototype?

Comment: what does your `create()` method looks like? Sample project would be helpful