# How to use AWS Amplify in React Native with Typescript Project?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add Amplify Authentication in my react native project which uses typescript.
There is a package given in amplify documentation **'aws-amplify-react-native'** which is used as a middleware to authenticate our application.
But this package is only supported in projects which are based on javascript.
For Typescript it shows an error like

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-amplify-react-native'.
Try `npm install @types/aws-amplify-react-native` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'aws-amplify-react-native';`
```

There is no package available like **'@types/aws-amplify-react-native'**

So anyone can help me out of this?

Comment: install aws-amplify and aws-amplify-react-native.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately there are no defined types at the time of this answer. However, you can invoke `@ts-ignore` like so

```
// @ts-ignore
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
// @ts-ignore
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// @ts-ignore
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native'

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

Comment: Sir I am facing similar issues where should it be add this be added

Answer (score 8):

There are no official TypeScript (TS) types available for *aws-amplify-react-native* at the moment. To suppress the TypeScript warning, you need to define your own TS declaration file (**.d.ts*).

To get approximate typings, you can copy [this file](https://github.com/dantasfiles/AmplifyReactNativeTypes/blob/master/aws-amplify-react-native.d.ts) into your project. These are typings written by the GitHub user [dantasfiles](https://github.com/dantasfiles). Bear in mind that they are not exact and could be specified more precisely.

Comment: Sir I am facing the same issues here could you help me I have imported the fire but still don't know how to configure it

Comment: @GeorgeSMulbahII Once you have the TS declaration file (.d.ts) in your project, you simply need to ensure it's included in your tsconfig.json with [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) and not [excluded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude). The TS compiler can then couple these types to the amplify package based on `declare module 'aws-amplify-react-native'`.

Comment: For more information, refer to e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript.

Comment: This is great (and helps a lot) but how is this a stable solution? I guess I'm confused (coming from Haskell) how TypeScript isn't just a mess (in practice): if package implementations and type definitions are separated, the whole thing makes very little sense and solves no actual problems. What am I missing?

Comment: @orome I guess that the short answer is that this is a JavaScript ecosystem and JS is a dynamically typed language. TypeScript (which is a superset of JS) types can be offered separately or included in an npm package, or, as in this case, not at all.