# What is the meaning of these extensions? What are these extensions used for?

Tags: javascript, nodejs-server

What is the meaning of these extentions?
What are these extensions used for?
When I look into a simple project & I see these extentions as in the attached image:(.config.js | .d.ts | .server.js)

[image: a snapshot of these extentions]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21247278/3001761, and config is short for "configuration" (the actual extensions are just .ts - TypeScript and .js - JavaScript).

Comment: thank you so much  jonrsharpe, one last question i still dont understand why we have to use typescript in nodejs & javascript project?

Comment: You don't have to. But those types can be used by e.g. IDEs to help autocompletion.