# Why 'declare global' in typescript doesnt work in .d.ts

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing window in my typescript project and I have to implement interface window as well.

Although works in typescript file doesn't make any difference in declaration type file

This work:

```js
// somefile.ts

declare global {
  interface Window {
    something: boolean
  }
}

window.something = true
```

Not working:

```js
// global.d.ts
declare global {
  interface Window {
    something: boolean
  }
}

// =============
// something.ts

window.something = true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About "\*.d.ts" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript)

Comment: Not actually @AlexYu here in the typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html) has the same example, but not working here

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add `export {}` to the `global.d.ts` file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).