# How to enforce the declaration of a function or the type of a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here is my problem :

I would like to make a file with the model of functions in typescript.
This declaration file will be used by different people to make their program on their side.

So i made an def.d.ts with a little example (i've tried both or one of them):

```
declare function printhello( name: string ): string;
//type printhello = ( name: string ) => string;
```

then a little program to see if my defintion of print hello is enforced by my ide (visual studio code).

```
/// <reference path="./types/common/def.d.ts" />


function printhello(name: string):void
{
    let say_hello:string = "Hello, i am ";
    say_hello.concat(name);
    // return say_hello;
}

let name_hello:string = "Percy";
console.log(printhello(name_hello));
```

But in this app.ts file i see when i pass my mouse on the printhello function that the ide know that it should take a string and a return a string, but it seems to have no problem with returning void ...

I activated the     "strictFunctionTypes": true,   in the tsconfig.json

regards

Comment: Why do you have `declare function` *and* `type`

Comment: @youdateme i've tried both or one of them

Comment: Unfortunately "module types" (e. g. enforcing the shape of a _module_ like one would enforce the shape of any other object) isn't something that TypeScript supports yet.  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/420 (it's been a _long_ time)

Comment: Maybe a test? the others programmers would be able to create "wrong code", but at least it wont go to your master branch as they will hit a wall when trying to merge their PR.

Comment: If you are writing the `printHello` function yourself, then a `declare` statement is unnecessary, just declare the function normally. Otherwise, if you are writing an API which requires other code to provide a `printHello` function of the correct type, then the `printHello` function can be accepted as an argument to some function, and then its type will be checked when that function is called.

Answer (score 3):

"Enforcement" in any context is a relationship. The developers who are participating by writing implementations of the types that you define must somehow comply with your expectations (you must decide how this process works).

In your question, you suggest that they will use a triple-slash reference to guide them. You rely on their compliance in this way (which is fine), but this is not the only option.

Alternatively, you can type the data structures that you would like to be enforced, and they can apply them as type annotations directly. If their implementations deviate from your definitions, a compiler error will appear. Consider this example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEBUAsFNQBwDYEMCeBzATgewK4DsATUAraAZzwHIAXUMnOOLDWgWxwWoEtFYAzLgnIAaOllABJSggSgcZWElB4krcnCQBjWNXFku7ZNR0xQ0AB5MWwA1eoBYAFBOQoALQfPX7z99--3i5gAGKC0ABcoDAyWAB01Chw5PFkQWaWzLQJSfAYXHjUABLQMaAAvKAAFCpqkWTUeXhoAJTlAHx0DfloANxOaQGDQ8NeaaFCkdEIcdSpjq62maDZsABUoEhkEInkoHzYrKCUscBTMztklH2ONepasOAXoADeTqDpdss7uflFJdPlKq3OpdJqtModeqNXpOAC+-UcmiweHqPwKxRikUeSTIsTgjT+pQq1VUEU60OakQAblguEQIS9QMBVm93myAH6crncpzY2CUEm1cndcEdGl0yigLhbPBYWibfRoFQAIyEy3EKyO+N+GOmx1ZfKO4oIkulyjlGzIipVat0XxylCh3WOs0qACYAMxut2tVbABHvIS0MioAD6Z3CTqagMouqwoi4G0OV1ZIZQ4f+cSReE0SGogugzWu71cGGg1BwGDwdDDZ2u8OcjiDylJGcxwujFUoAAVoBhNCgU4jkWQsEJYtM0JVtejMwW29NmkWnEA)

`./hello.types.ts`:

```ts
export type printHello = (name: string) => string;
```

`./hello.ts`:

```ts
import type * as Types from './hello.types';

const printHello: Types.printHello = (name: string): void => { /*
      ~~~~~~~~~~
Type '(name: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'printHello'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322) */

  let say_hello:string = 'Hello, i am ';
  say_hello.concat(name);
  // return say_hello;
}

let name_hello: string = 'Percy';
console.log(printHello(name_hello));
```

Another advantage to this approach is that they won't need to re-type any types from the imports. Re-using the above example:

```ts
const printHello: Types.printHello = (name) => `Hello, i am ${name}`;
//                                   ^^^^^^
// No parameter annotation or return type annotation,
// which is ok because the variable itself is already
// annotated by the imported type and thus uses that information
```

> Note that I didn't use the idiomatic PascalCase for the type name because the intention is to import all exports from the types module (effectively creating a namespace), and then the names of the types will also serve as a guide for the developers as to how to name their corresponding data structures.

Answer (score 0):

`interfaces` are a great mechanism to provide implementers with a declaration that you'd like them to adhere to. Here's an example `interface` based on your requirements:

```
interface HelloPrinter {
  printHello(name: string): string
}
```

Upon giving this to someone to implement, they can create a class that adheres to this interface. If I write:

```
class HelloPrinterImpl implements HelloPrinter {
  
}
```

TypeScript validly complains:

```
  Property 'printHello' is missing in type 'HelloPrinterImpl' but required in type 'HelloPrinter'.

13 class HelloPrinterImpl implements HelloPrinter {}
```

At this point, you can create your implementation:

```
class HelloPrinterImpl implements HelloPrinter {
  printHello(name: string): string {
    const hello = "Hello, i am ";
    return hello.concat(name);
  }
}
```

You can keep these interfaces all in a separate file, such as an `interfaces.ts` file, if you so please.

If you're doing this to, say, create an API where developers have to adhere to your spec, you can create functions that accept these interfaces as parameters. Then they can pass any implementations that meet your declaration. Here's an example:

```
function bodyOfWork(printer: HelloPrinter) {
  // Perform some work here
  printer.printHello("someone who gets work done.")
}

bodyOfWork(new HelloPrinterImpl()) // => Hello, i am someone who gets work done.
```

This is not the only way to do this. You can accomplish this with types as well. For instance, if you create a function type that accepts a string and returns a string and then request that as a parameter, your implementers will only be able to pass a function that adheres to this spec:

```
type helloPrinter = (name: string) => string

function bodyOfWorkWithTypes(print: helloPrinter) {
  // Perform some work here
  print("someone who gets work done.")
}

bodyOfWorkWithTypes(message => "Hello! I am ".concat(message))
// => Hello! I am someone who gets work done.
```

You can export this type too, and add it to a separate file:

```
export type helloPrinter = (name: string) => string
```

TypeScript is very flexible, and there's many different ways to adhere to your requirements. Hope this helps

#### Sidenote: using `.d.ts`

If you're using TypeScript 2.x+, you don't need to use `.d.ts` files. [These files are meant for JavaScript libraries that need to expose TypeScript bindings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21247316/1603399) `/// reference` was previously used to load `.d.ts` files in contexts where type definitions were not available. This is no longer necessary.

Regardless, with `strictFunctionTypes` set to `true`, your code does not compile for me:

```
def.d.ts:1:18 - error TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

1 declare function printhello(name: string): string;
```

You can save yourself a lot of headache by just avoiding this pattern. Delete the `.d.ts` file and you'll have the proper error for your use case:

```
index.ts:1:36 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

1 function printhello(name: string): string {
                                     ~~~~~~
```

At this point you can fix your function with the proper types:

```
function printHello(name: string): string {
  const hello = "Hello, i am ";
  return hello.concat(name);
}
```

TypeScript is really good at understanding what types are returned by your function, so you can simplify even more:

```
function printHello(name: string) {
  const hello = "Hello, i am ";
  return hello.concat(name);
}
```

One last note: if you require types to be exported because you're making a JavaScript library, you can set enable it at the compiler level:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

This will generate `.d.ts` files for you.