# Include a Javascript file in a Typescript Ionic project

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

This took me a few hours to solve and I read through a lot of obsolete posts, so I am posting this a new question.
How to add and import a javascript file in a Ionic project using a `d.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

After many trials I created a new Ionic React app from the Ionic Appflow Dashboard and managed to use some existing JS files. Here is a basic example.

```
//test.js
export function testMsg(msg:string){
    alert(msg)
}
```

```
//test.d.ts
declare module 'test' {
    export function testMsg(msg) : void;
  }
```

```
//Import and use
import {testMsg} from './test'

testMsg('test');
```

Visual code complains about the imported file not being a module but the code works.

I added these lines under `compilerOptions` and updated the "include" value in `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/**/*.d.ts"],
  ...
```

Comment: If your not going to add any type information just import the `.js` file, no need for a `.d.ts`,  you only use a `.d.ts` file if you want to add types,.   `export function testMsg(msg:string) : void;`    <-- you forgot the type of `msg`