# How to import Class type definitions in .js file using JSDocs from a type declaration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

See below screenshot. I'm trying to get IDE autocompletion/type-checking goodness in my JS files by defining my TS type declarations in another file, and importing them. While I've been able to figure this out using simple variables and functions, I am unable to do this with a class definition.

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

[image: example]

Comment: You shouldn't need to import your type declarations at all to manually annotate each js variable with its type. Easiest way would be to put your declaration file at *lib/Movable.d.ts* instead of *types/index.ts*, but you can also [reference it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091724/search-path-for-typescript-d-ts-files) or for a library [specify its location in the *package.json*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html). Also, why not just annotate your declarations directly in the jsdoc comments instead of maintaining a separate file?